# rkt/image building: acbuild run instructions "ignored"

Tags: rkt

I'm experiencing unexpected behavior using `acbuild run`. To get used to rkt the idea was to start with a CentOS7 based container running a SSH host. The bare CentOS 7 container referenced below as `centos7.aci` was created on a up-to-date CentOS7 install using the instructions given [here](https://www.sidorenko.io/post/2016/07/creating-container-base-image-of-centos/).
The script used to build the SSHd ACI is

```
#! /bin/bash
acbuild begin ./centos7.aci
acbuild run -- yum install -y openssh-server
acbuild run -- mkdir /var/run/sshd
acbuild run -- sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
acbuild run -- sed 's@session\s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional pam_loginuid.so@g' -i /etc/pam.d/sshd
acbuild run -- ssh-keygen -A -C "" -N "" -q
acbuild run -- echo 'root:screencast' | chpasswd
acbuild set-name centos7-sshd
acbuild set-exec -- /usr/sbin/sshd -D
acbuild port add ssh tcp 22
acbuild write --overwrite centos7-sshd.aci
acbuild end
```

When it's spinned up using `rkt run --insecure-options=image ./centos7-sshd.aci`
the server runs but connection attempts fail because the password is not accepted. If I use `rkt enter` to get into the running container and re-run `echo 'root:screencast' | chpasswd` inside, I can login. So that acbuild run instruction has just not worked for some reason... To test a bit more, I replaced it by 
`acbuild run -- mkdir ~/.ssh
acbuild run -- echo "<rkt host SSH public key>“ >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

to enable key based instead of password login. It doesn't work: the key is refused. The reason is obvious once you look into the container: there's no `authorized_keys` file in `~/.ssh/`. If I add a
`acbuild run -- touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` instruction before the key appending attempt, the file is created but it's still empty. So again a  acbuild run instruction didn't work - without error notice. May it be related to the fact that both „ignored“ instructions use operators like `>>` and `|` ? All commands shown in the examples I've seen don't use any such operators yet the [docs](https://github.com/containers/build/blob/master/Documentation/subcommands/run.md) don't mention anything and a Google search doesn't help either. In dockerfile `RUN` instructions they also work fine... what is going wrong here?

P.S.: I tried to use the `chroot` instead of the default `systemd-nspawn` engine in the „ignored“ `acbuild run` instructions => same results

P.P.S.: there's no `acbuild` tag yet on StackOverflow so I had to tag this as `rkt` - could somebody with enough reputation create one please? Thx

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I understood what happens using the the `acbuild run --debug` option. 
When

`acbuild run -- echo 'root:screencast' | chpasswd`

gets executed it returns `Running: [echo root:screencast]` , the pipe is executed on the host machine. To get the intended result it should be

`acbuild run -- /bin/sh -c "echo 'root:screencast' | chpasswd"`

or in generic form

`acbuild run -- /bin/sh -c "<cmd with pipes>"`

as explained [here](https://github.com/containers/build/issues/310)